# Facebook Open Graph API returns: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to publish actions to a user's wall using the Open Graph API.

I requested the 'publish_actions' permission, enabled the 'Enhanced Auth Dialog', my role is set to 'developer' and my app settings show 'This app may post on your behalf, including pictureabcs you viewabcked and more.'.

Requesting

```
$facebook->api('/me/permissions');
```

returns

```
array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["installed"]=> int(1) ["publish_actions"]=> int(1) } } }
```

However, when I send the following post request

```
$data = array();
$data['access_token'] = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$data['pictureabc'] = 'http://###url###';
$facebook->api($app_id . '/liveluvcreate:viewabc', 'post', $data);
```

I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions thrown...
```

as result.

Any suggestions?

Best, Sebastian

Comment: Is your application sandboxed? This may (or may not) be related to existing bug [Can't publish opengraph actions to app admin.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/341769392537747)

Comment: No, it is not sandboxed. I just sandboxed it but the error stays the same.

Comment: @PartieSturm How did you solved this problem?. Because i am facing the same problem. Can you share with me what you have done for this problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `$app_id` is not the id of user owning the `access_token`.

You better use `/me/liveluvcreate:viewabc` just to be sure you publishing action to user owning `access_token` and who have `publish_actions` granted to your app.

```
$facebook->api('/me/liveluvcreate:viewabc', 'post', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be very late to post an answer[but it might be helpful to others], but as of 2014 if you want to post anything  to the user[apart from the app registered developer] timeline you need Facebook permission i.e the app needs to be submitted for approval
Please refer the following link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

you can check that it's right below the overview section.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Thank you for this useful information. It seems there is no such problem for apps created before 2014. As I have an old app which requires `publish_actions` and it's still working fine.