# PHP sdk to facebook page post, Uncaught OAuthException: (#200)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I keep getting:

"Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

```
require_once("resources/facebook_sdk/facebook.php");

    $app_id       = 'appid';
    $app_secret   = 'appsecret';


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user)
    {

        $access_token=  $facebook->getAccessToken();

    }

    else {

        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'canvas' => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'scope' => 'offline_access,read_stream,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,manage_pages'
        ));
        echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>");
    }




    $req =  array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'name' => 'My wall post',
        'message' => 'tralalala',
        'caption' => "www.mysite.com",
        'link' => 'http://www.mysite.com',
        'description' => 'Wall post',
        'picture' => 'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/1111/some-pic.jpg',
        'actions' => array(array('name' => 'My Site',
            'link' => 'http://www.mysite.com'))
    );

    print_r($req);
    $res = $facebook->api('/pageid/feed' ,'post',$req);
    if ($res) echo "succes";
    else echo "fail";
    print_r($res);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, publish stream permission is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is taken in to consideration that you have all rights of server to upload on Facebook.Checkout some of links below for more information,

[Facebook API OAuthException: (#200)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158164/facebook-api-oauthexception-200)

[Facebook Open Graph API returns: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473797/facebook-open-graph-api-returns-200-requires-extended-permission-publish-ac)

[Uncaught OAuthException: (#200), when trying to post on wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726359/uncaught-oauthexception-200-when-trying-to-post-on-wall)

[Multiuser event invite graph api fails Permissions Error:200 OAuthException](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/312375168858626?browse=search_5017eadead76b7a22667493)

You have give all permission which you define in scope,

```
'scope'=>'offline_access,read_stream,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,manage_pages';
```

may help you.

Comment: @Phoenix_yay can you just write publish_stream in scope & check what will be done?

Comment: @Phoenix_yay can you solved this issue or find some problem, my answer help you or not?