# Facebook PHP SDK Upload Images - Path of Image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

providing option on website to click and upload image on facebook:
Got this code after search

```
$pic = $_GET['PhotoID']; //example: http//www.mysite.com/content/2013/03/image.jpg
copy($pic, 'tmp/file.jpg');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath('tmp/file.jpg');
$publish = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
unlink('tmp/file.jpg');
```

This code is working fine. 
But Copying image to tmp take some time I want to speed up the process.
(uploading images from my website only no external image)

How can I use this code without copying to temp:

```
 $pic = $_GET['PhotoID']; //example: http://www.mysite.com/content/2013/03/image.jpg
    $args['image'] = '@' . realpath('$pic');
    $publish = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

not sure about usage of '@' & realpath
Can i use full image url without using realpath:

```
`$args['image'] = $pic;
        $publish = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);`
```

& what is the best way to show error message if user dnt authorize the application. 
or errors like Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException occurs

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/14726580/718224 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/14937938/718224

Comment: @AdvaitAmin sorry its not related to ques. i want example code  with absolute path of image (full url of image)

Comment: your problem is Copying image to tmp take some time you want to speed up the process means uploading process taking too much time...

Comment: yes I want to directly use image url($pic) in $publish instead of tmp file copy process

Comment: check my edit answer which i gave link above.

Comment: realpath($FILE_PATH) value is not clear ! its essential to 1st copy images to tmp/file.jpg How can I use direct Image file path "http//www.mysite.com/content/2013/03/image.jpg" instead of tmp/file

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to copy image to `/tmp`. you can directly upload image by providing image url itself in parameter. the below code should work:

```
$picUrl = 'http//www.mysite.com/content/2013/03/image.jpg';
$photoId = $facebook->api("me/photos","POST",array('url'=>$picUrl,'message'=>"status message")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same in my app,jst go with this..
make sure that you have the permission publish_stream

```
$attachment = array(
                'message' => 'Message',
                'name' =>'your app name',
                'caption' => "caption under the image",
                'link' => 'your link',
                'description' => 'description regarding the image',
                'picture' => 'path of the picture(doesnt work for the local path, should be server path)',
                'method'=>'stream.publish',
                'actions' => array(
                                array(
                                  'name' => 'App name',
                                  'link' => 'your app link'
                                )
                            )
                );
```

then after

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

here $uid is your user id of the facebook, which you can get from the facebook config file

```
$facebook = new Facebook('configure your facebook config file here');    
$my_details = $facebook->api('/me');
$uid = $my_details['id'];  // id of the user
```