# "Like" facebook button in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook

I am developing wpf application and I have a like button that contains the image and number of  likes.

Can anyone help with http link which I will put in the button.

Thanks

Code that I tried:

```
[RequiresPermissions(new[] { "publish_actions" })]
    public void LikePost(string id)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(ConfigurationProvider.CurrentConfiguration.FacebookAuthToken);
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = id;
        var res = fb.Post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=POST&object=http%3A%2F%2Fsamples.ogp.me%2F", parameters); 
    }
```

Error is: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will get better help if you post some code and the type of error you are getting

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10473797/2256349)